# Laptop won't shutdown or reboot

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, laptop, reboot, logs

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04** on a **HP 17-ak032nf** laptop.

I got a really annoying problem, when I try to reboot or shutdown it, it will just leave a blank screen but I can still hear the fan, and sometimes the DELs stays on too.

Feel free to ask anything you need to find the source of it, because I always have to force shutdown by pressing the power button.

I've tried much solutions involving editing Grub, maybe some of you got the right one for my problem !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since the kernel 5.11.0-41 and mesa opengl  were updated on December 2, 2021.

A possible solution may be to use the old kernel 5.11.0-38 generic, work's fine in HP computer.

Comment: Where do I find the package ? And what is the différence between these two ?

Comment: In the computer it can be installed already, it is selected through grub, at the beginning it is pressed uppercase and it shows advanced options menu, it is tested with this kernel.

Comment: I tried with kernel 5.11.0-38 generic, it sure shutdowns, but it takes a few minutes, any idée how to fix ? (changing timeout in systemd doesn't affect duration)

Comment: Check which processes are causing a prolonged shutdown in Linux
If you want to find out what is wrong, you need to check what happened on the last shutdown. # journalctl -rb -1
The journalctl command allows you to read the system logs. With the '-b -1' options, filter the logs from the last boot session. With the '-r' option, the records are displayed in reverse chronological order.

In other words, the 'journalctl -rb -1' command will display the system logs just before your Linux system was shut down for the last time. This is what you need to analyze the long shutdown problem in Linux.