# System not be able to enter suspend mode

Tags: suspend

For a few days, the system has not been able to enter suspend mode. Could someone give me some advice on where to start looking?

Screens (2) goes completely blank, the cursor on the up left side blinking, and the only solution is turn off the computer.

My version is 20.04

**Inxi output:**

```
Graphics: Device-1: NVIDIA driver: nvidia v: 495.29.05 
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 
driver: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa    
resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 495.29.05
```

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your post and add the result from `inxi -G`(executed in the terminal). I suspect that you have a NVIDIA GPU...

Comment: `inxi -G` please - and [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1383430/edit) your post instead of answering in comments. People that try to help you are not inclined to browse thru the comments to gather all infos needed

Comment: Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: nvidia v: 495.29.05 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa 
  resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070/PCIe/SSE2 
  v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 495.29.05

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in this

Answer (score 1):

Since devices are more and specific to the Windows OS and the native binary NVIDIA driver mediocre at best you might have chance to make the acpi parts needed by nvidia get running again. [Here](https://iam.tj/prototype/enhancements/Windows-acpi_osi.html) is a pretty detailed explanation.

Basically you should try to tell a part of the firmware, that you are "window" device.

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

There is a line that starts with:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="...."

(The dots mean that there might be an entry inside)
Add the following definition:

`acpi_osi=\"Windows 2015\"`

into that line so it looks like this: (do not overwrite entries, just add)

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=\"Windows 2015\""`

close the editor with keyboard keys Crtl+x (thats how nano works) and issue the command

`sudo update-grub`

reboot

If it doesn't help or you've got problems after restart: simply repeat the steps above and remove the entry, save the file and call `update-grub`again - so no harm is done.

Good luck

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't work. Thank you for all !!!

Comment: Yes, there is a 50% percent chance for it to work. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: hi worked for me, but for the power button suspend method and not the command with systemctl . thanks mucho. though I feel dirty putting 'Windows' anything on my machine. , side note HP Envy BIOS updates USB must be done IN windows. 5.11.0-43-generic  20.04.1. previously I got no suspend and no return from the dead, and previous to that, say 4 months ago, it did work. Ryzen 5

Comment: I can attest to the 50% rule. It did not work on my other laptop, also a ryzen 5 but 3500 up from 2500. I got blank screen, no flashing power button, and on 'resume' the crazy 'test pattern' display . had to use the ubuntu top bar menu too to get that far. ubuntu was cloned onto this other machine. and both are running 5.11.0-43 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383245/laptop-wont-shutdown-or-reboot) we have a similar problem, we could not turn off the computer, the problem came with the kernel update, on December 2, 2021, and what I found out is that with kernel 5.11.0-38 it works, I have nvidia graph radeon5. In the current kernel (5.11.0-43) I know from the log that there are problems with acpi video, it does not load brightness control.